# lidar: number of samples - impact w/ Navigation stack?

Tags: navigation, lidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 360 degree lidar (Neato) with 1 degree resolution (360 samples/rev) running with Navigation stack.  The setting for the AMCL is set to use 60 samples per rev. Seems to be working OK.

I will soon have a bandwidth issue with my data channel so am considering throwing out 50% of the samples at the transmitter of the lidar data, so would be reducing data to 180 samples/rev. By my understanding this should have no impact on the performance of the Navigation stack since it will only use 60 samples regardless of getting 360 or 180 samples.

Is my understanding correct? No impact? Does it matter if I throw out odds or evens?

FYI: the bandwidth issue is caused by needing to add additional data source to the channel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241359/lidar:-number-of-samples---impact-w/-navigation-stack?/) by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1850 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll answer this one myself now that I've made the change and see the results.
Reducing the resolution from 1 degree to 2 degrees had no detectable impact on performance.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2016-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0